# Switch between the workspaces (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, workspaces, workspace-switcher

How can I switch between the workspaces?
In ubuntu 12.10 , there was a workspace window to switch between 4 workspaces ....
But I cannot find a way to switch between the workspaces in ubuntu 14.04....

Answer (score 2):

Open *System Settings* and click on *Appearance*

[image]

Now, select the *Enable Workspaces* box

[image]

You will now have a Workspace Switcher on your Unity launcher

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a good way to customize whatever you want including workspaces in ubuntu 14.04.
Install Unity tweak tool by the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Open the Unity tweak tool ([know more about Unity tweak tool](http://sourcedigit.com/8266-15-powerful-unity-tweak-tool-customizations-ubuntu-14-04/)) and go to "Hot Corners".

Then add workspace to one of the corners (it is usual to put it on top left in [GNOME 3](http://www.gnome.org/gnome-3/)). Enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

Once enabled, as described by Rohith Madhavan, you can switch manually by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> plus left, right, up and down arrow keys or by selecting the Workspace Switcher on the Unity launcher